# How to fix IE layout issue User Interface design (flexlayout, scss and angular)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, sass, cross-browser, angular-flex-layout

I would like to seek assistance on making a x-browser compatibility UI. Im currently writing a component using angular flexlayout and scss to a certain design..i wanted to achieve this design

**everything renders correctly except for the IE 11**

[image]

but on IE it is rendering differently. here what it looks like on IE

[image]

here;s my template code:

```
<div class="balance-widget__container" matRipple (click)="onBalanceWidgetClicked()">
  <div class="balance-widget__header mat-{{ headerColor }} py-16" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">{{ headerLabel }}</div>
  <div class="ftr-balance-widget__container-details" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <mat-progress-spinner class="ftr-balance-widget__container-details-spinner" mode="determinate" value="100" [color]="ringColor" [strokeWidth]="strokeWidth" [diameter]="diameter"></mat-progress-spinner>
    <div class="ftr-balance-widget__container-details-values w-100 h-100" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          <div>30</div>
          <div>Available</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ftr-balance-widget__container-details-values-divider px-8 py-8" style="width:120px;" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          <div class="ftr-balance-widget__container-details-values-divider-line" fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          </div>
          <div class="ftr-balance-widget__container-details-values-divider-subheader">{{ subHeaderLabel }}</div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          <div>Balance</div>
          <div>2333</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's the scss:

```
.balance-widget__container {
    background-color: $normal-background;
    
    &-details {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;

        &-spinner {
            position: relative;
        }
        
        &-values {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top:0;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            margin: auto;

            &-divider {
                position: relative;

                &-line {
                    position: relative;
                    background-color: $primary5;
                }

                &-subheader {
                    background-color: $normal-background;
                    position: absolute;
                    left:100%;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just looking at your screenshot - it seems to be a simple position rendering issue of the element that displays 'Entitlement', and it should be an easy fix. You Sass code seems fine to me, but your markup is full of logic and very Angular heavy, so it's difficult for others to see what's going on without a running demo or your codebase. I'd suggest to strip the DOM back to the very necessary elements, and use static values instead of Angular models, so that we can help you better. Question - what version of IE are we talking?

Comment: @robertp thanks for replying men, i have updated the template and the IE version is 11

Comment: I try to test your above code sample by creating a new Angular app but due to many things missing in the above code example, the project generates many errors. I suggest you please try to provide a code sample that we can directly try to run with the IE 11 browser that can help us to reproduce the issue. If possible you can also try to share the sample using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/). It can really help us to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.